# pear shows a weird PHP warning every time I execute any command

Tags: php, sqlite, pear

Whenever I use pear, I get this strange warning message:

```
$ pear list
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
...
...
```

It always shows up. Strangely, pear seems to be functioning just fine. Is this a common problem? Does anyone know how to fix it? I'm running Leopard 10.5.8, here's my version:

```
$ pear version
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Darwin robert-martins-mac.local 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: \
Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

**Edit: Solution found.** For posterity, the problem was my php.ini file. I was including a module in php.ini (sqlite3) that was already compiled into php. The site that solved this for me was this: http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my php.ini file.

I was including a module in php.ini (sqlite3) that was already compiled into php. The site that solved this for me was this: http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** I am aware the following answer has nothing to do with the question. I screwed up. I keep this answer posted because of the comments below.

Without code to look at, this is a shot into the blue, but I would make sure to use

`include_once()` and `require_once()`

instead of

`include()` and `require()`

While the `*_once()` take the fraction of a millisecond longer to execute, they make sure that libraries are not loaded twice ... thus getting rid of these kind of warnings.

Comment: It's the official pear code, not mine, so that might be the problem but if it is it's a bug in pear. Do you think that's likely?

Comment: Such "bugs" happen - but `warning`s are often ignored by developers (which is a *bad* practice) as they are no "real" problem for program execution. You should be able to disable these kind of warnings in your php.ini (`display_errors`, which should be false in production systems...)

Comment: Well, I'm using this setup for development so disabling warnings is not an option. I don't want to be the _bad_ practice developer you're talking about...

Comment: Then - as uncomfortable as it sounds - in your case I would just ignore those warnings. Wading through third-party code just to get rid of some minor error messages is simply not worth the trouble, and the system seems to work...